# Which application path to use for Windows IIS in Advanced Firewall Rules?

Tags: iis, asp.net, windows-firewall

I'd like to unblock my IIS ASP.NET 4.5 webservice for public access.

In Windows 10 Advanced Firewall Rules I added an inbound rule to accept all incoming requests for my webservice's port (e.g. `8001`). That's working fine with "allow all programs".

However, I'd like to further restrict this rule to only work for IIS.

But none of the restrictions I set so far worked:

- Setting program path `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe`, or
- Setting service to `WWW Publishing Service - W3SVC`

What service do I need to choose?

Comment: It is the `http.sys` driver that hooks to the port, so your selection of those user mode processes for firewall rules does not work.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! Is there an option to restrict the firewall rule to this driver?

Comment: After you told IIS to listen to port 8001, `http.sys` will listen on that port and no other process can listen to the same port, so there isn't really any need to restrict the firewall rule any further.

Comment: I comprehend. I just want to make sure none of my colleagues is going to alter configuration by removing the IIS:8001 website and thereby opening doors for someone adding some potential malware program, handling :8001 requests instead. Thus my question.